# Hidden Doxygen labels in markdowns?

Tags: markdown, doxygen, github-flavored-markdown

For embedding markdown files in Doxygen generated documentation, I have got "subpaging" to work by using header labels such as this

```
MyFile.md Title {#myFile}
====

# Section 1
Blabla
```

They can then be referenced by `@subpage myFile` and voilà! Clean sub paging in the Doxygen generated documentation.

However, these headers/titles quickly become quite verbose in a large project.

It is fine in the Doxygen generated documentation, but the raw markdowns loose their appeal and any benefits of having them close to the code on e.g GitHub.

---

I have tried

```
MyFile.md Title <!--{#myFile}-->
====
```

without success.

---

**Is there a way to create these labels for Doxygen's `@subpage`, without ruining the markdown experience?**

---

**Edit:** I'm using Doxygen v1.8.13

Comment: First again: Which version of doxygen? (I know you still use 1.8.13 but other and future users won't know).

Comment: @albert I knew you'd find this ;) For the record, this is a side track I'm investigating in addition to what I asked on my last post. Thank you for asking about the version again though!

Comment: The `<!--{#myFile}-->` is also seen by doxygen as comment. In case no label present doxygen will create an own label (for internal referencing), but this label might change between versions and is only for internal use, so not really usable for one's own usage.

Comment: That explains why it did not work. Would a `[comment]: <> (something)` syntax be picked up as a comment for Doxygen as well?

Comment: I'm not 100% getting what you mean, but when I understand it correctly `[comment]:` would be in the text, this will be picked up by doxygen as normal text.

Comment: I was thinking of adding the anchor in a out commented block for the markdown parser but visible for the Doxygen compiler. Something like `# My Page [comment]: <> (#my-anchor)`, but this does not work since the comment only works on its own line.